# Run cmd.exe with specified parametrs from Javascript

Tags: javascript, shell, command-line, cmd

Colls, I wrote a script which should:

1. copy a file from C:\PR\DataFiles\Input\CL_CH5\"+k+"\ext_028042012.dat to  C:\PR\DataFiles\Input\ext_028042012.dat - works fine
2. run cmd.exe with specified command line (p.3)
3. after runing cmd.exe, script should go to c: disk, than change directory to c:/pr, then write in cmd line «process.bat c:\pr ext_028042012.dat auto» and press Enter.

**Code is**:

```
 var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
     for (var k = -2; k <= 0; k++)  
     {  
         var out_dir = "C:\\PROBE\\DataFiles\\Input\\CL_CH5";  
         // now i am copying a ext_028042012 to destination folder    
         fso.CopyFile("C:\\PR\\DataFiles\\Input\\CL_CH5\\"+k+"\\ext_028042012.dat",                                                                            
         "C:\\PR\\DataFiles\\Input\\ext_028042012.dat", 1);  
         WScript.Echo(k+"file copied.");  
         /*Block which run cmd window*/  
         //The following code should open a command window, changes to the path to C:\ ,   and executes the DIR command.
         var oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell");  
         **oShell.run ("cmd /K cd c:\pr /K process.bat c:\ext_028042012.dat auto");**  
         WScript.Echo(k+ "file proceed!!!");
```

1. Unfortunatly, it doesn't work. Script doesn't put command line from p.3 to opened cmd.exe window.
   Please, tell me where is my mistake. Thank you a lot.

Comment: What error you get? And how you run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true) string,

```
"cmd /K cd c:\pr /K process.bat c:\ext_028042012.dat auto"
```

looks erroneous. I don't believe you can specify several `/K` commands like that - and since the meaning of `/K` is *"Carry out the command and continue"* never ending the first shell you launch.

Have you tried:

```
"cmd /K cd c:\pr && process.bat c:\ext_028042012.dat auto"
```

Comment: result: 'The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\PR\DataFiles\Input>' - nothing changes =(

Comment: Is that error from the `fso.CopyFile` line, or is something within `process.bat`? Does the folder exist?

Comment: exactly!!! there was problem with in incorrect path. also i should use double slash instead "\". Do you want to let cmd.exe know wait for pressing enter after "c:\pr && process.bat c:\ext_028042012.dat auto"? i try to use \k and \c, but have no effect.